# Prove that series convergent if and only if t>0

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that series convergent if and only if $t>0$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^ \infty   \frac{(-1)^{n - 1}\sin{\ln{n}}}{n^t}$$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam it's not so obvious

Comment: I said for $t>1$ it converges    absolutly.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam definitely, but there may be a conditional convergence, if t <=0. So, the task is to prove, that series diverges, if t<=0, and convergent, if t > 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for $t>1$**

we have that $\forall n\in \mathbb N$

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n\sin(\ln(n))}{n^t}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n^t}$$

and the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^t}$ converges if $t>1$, thus by comparison test, your series converges.